# Using DateAdd in umbraco xslt to display next year's date

Tags: xslt, umbraco

I'm trying to display the date for a year from now in an xslt file using umbraco like so:

```
<xsl:variable name="now" select="umbraco.library:CurrentDate()"/>
<xsl:value-of select="umbraco.library:DateAdd($now, 'year', 1)"/>
```

The value-of tag outputs today's date.  How can I get the DateAdd to add a year to the current date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constant 'year' is wrong.  It expects just 'y'.

```
<xsl:variable name="now" select="umbraco.library:CurrentDate()"/>
<xsl:value-of select="umbraco.library:DateAdd($now, 'y', 1)"/>
```